# How to use basic authentication in slim php?

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, http-authentication, slim-3

I am using slim framework to write my own API and everything is just fine but when I add the slim-basic-auth library to secure my API and test it .... I always get this error :

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\mydatabase\public\index.php:22

Any help with that please ?

I installed the library and use it just like in tutorial

```
$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
        "secure"=>false,
        "users" => [
                "userName@#" => "password#@"        ]
        ]));
```

Comment: You probably need to add the tuupola/slim-basic-auth package to your composer.json file.  This is an add-on and not included with Slim.  See composer require:  https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth

Comment: **I did it before man, and still get the error and actually that is what surprising me** @AlexBarker

Answer (score 1):

For anyone dealing with this issue: In addition to registering the middleware in your `Middlewares.php` (or where your `$app = new Slim\App;` is defined):

```php
return static function (App $app, Closure $customErrorHandler): void {
    <...>
    $app->add(new \Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
        "users" => [
            "somebody" => "passw0rd"
        ]
    ]));
};
```

If you're using fast CGI you must add this line to your `public/.htaccess` file to avoid getting 401 even with valid auth:

```
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Source: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67883

Answer (score 0):

you are missing backslash

`new Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication`

=>

`new \Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication`